# How can I change from comma-delimited to semi-colon delimited but don't change the commas that are in between quotes?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a comma delimited file that looks like the following:

```
123,456,"ABC,DEF"
```

I would like to change the file to a semi-colon delimited file:

```
123;456;"ABC,DEF"
```

I have the following that I run but unfortunately the , in the quotes is also changed to ;. How can I stop this from happening?

```
sed 's/,/;/g; s/\"//g; s/$/;^/' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can I change from comma-delimited to semi-colon delimited but
> don't change the commas that are in between quotes?

You can use `csvtool`. It is already packaged for many distributions. Handling the csv format with regular expressions can be both difficult and error prone.

```
$  csvtool -t ','   -u ';' col 1-  input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` with the double quote as fields separator and replace `,` with `;` only for the odd fields (1,3,5 etc).

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2) gsub(/,/,";",$i)}1' file
```

There are some assumptions made here, like that there are no `;` into the fields initially, no embedded/escaped `"` inside double quotes, but the input is simple like in the example.

To deal with more complex cases, GNU awk provides an `FPAT` [solution](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) for csv files, which is efficient in most cases, excluding cases like newlines into the fields. If this cvs cannot be assumed as simple as in the example, then a program using a library for cvs parsing is required.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1}1' file
123;456;"ABC,DEF"
```

If you need more than that then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk